# struts 2 Closing network connections after result

Tags: networking, connection, struts, inputstream

I use network connection from a struts application to connect to a network resource and download a file directly to the browser without storing it on the struts running server (need to avoid polluting the struts server with transported files). I use the result type stream to actually download the inputstream from the network resource directly to the user's browser and the inputstream is automatically closed but the network connection that carries the stream is never returned (there is a connection pool as I use httpclient for the network connection).

is there any way anyone can see to actually get code called after the result (of type stream) is finished (file has downloaded to the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is indeed solved by an interceptor:
I have written the following in an interceptor of the Action:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    try {
        return invocation.invoke();
    } finally {
        DownloadAction da = (DownloadAction) invocation.getAction();
        if (null != da && null != da.getResponse()) {
            logger.debug("@@@@@@ connection releasing");
            da.getResponse().releaseConnection();
        }else{
            logger.error("@@@@@@ connection cannot be released");
        }
    }
}
```

Contrary to my previous belief this actually runs only after all results are executed (stream downloaded). It turns out I had been releasing the connection way to soon so I was getting a confusing error in the logs that I thought it was because the interceptor was running too soon. I was wrong.

I hope this may one day help someone else out there.